# Custom Formatting dimensions of a box in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, vba

I am currently creating a spreadsheet in Excel and setting a standard for everything I am copying in. Some of the text I am entering is different to the format I want it in.

The format I want is for example: `233 X 223 X 34` Data coming in is usually: `233x233x34`

Is there any way to convert the text to the format I want it in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Include the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim r As Range
Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each r In Target
        v = r.Value
        If InStr(1, v, "X") > 0 Then
            r.Replace "X", " X "
            r.Replace "  X  ", " X "
        End If
    Next r
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```